# Bootstrap Modal UI not updating when the scope variable is updated in angular using setTimeout and $scope.$apply()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some issues on my bootstrap modal using angular js on which I would like to better understand why the scope variable is not updating. I have a page (let's call it main page) on which it contains a dropdown on which I can choose an entry.

```
   <p>@{{serv_id}}</p>
<select class="form-control" id="serv" ng-model="service_id" ng-change="selectServ()">
        <option value="179">Serv 1</option>
        <option value="180">Serv 2</option>
        <option value="181">Ser 3</option>
</select>
 <a href="" class="btn-getnum" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remote-serv-modal">
     Get this serv <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
 </a>
```

When the user selects an entry, the `ng-change="selectServ()"` function is triggered. Here is the code for the function which is a part of  `ng-controller="servController"`:

```
$scope.selectServ = function(){
      serv_id = $('#serv').val();
         $http.get('/serv/next-serv/' + serv_id).success(function(response){
            setTimeout(function(){
               $scope.serv_id = serv_id;
               $scope.$apply()
               $scope.selectServ();
            }, 5000);

        });
    };
```

When the user selects an entry, `<p>@{{serv_id}}</p>` found on the main page updates the output. However, the scope variable `$scope.serv_id` which is found on my modal which is included in my main page using `@include('modals.remote-queue-modal')` does not update.

Here is the code for the modal which is found on another blade:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="remote-serv-modal" tabindex="-1" ng-controller="servController">
      @{{serv_id}}
</div>
```

> I didn't include all the codes of my modal, but it has all the elements of a bootstrap modal (dialog, header and content). The important part of the code above is that it has a ng-controller and the scope variable.

What am I doing wrong? Anyone who can point me to a resource is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of $scope.selectServ().  Right now it really isn't doing anything.  It makes an http.get call but does nothing with the return data.  It sets $scope.serv_id equal to $('#serv').val() which is unnecessary since $('#serv').val() is the same as $scope.service_id that is part of your model.  Beyond that you haven't shown us the code for your modal which is where you think your problem lies.

Comment: Get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap. And stop using jQuery in controllers. There should be no DOM code there. Your data models should be driving the dom not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that you are having is you are operating on things outside of angular so you either need to $apply your changes through a timeout or just do things more in an angular way.

Quick answer

```
angular.module('snrApp').controller("servController", ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.selectServ = function(){
        var serv_id = $('#serv').val();
        $http.get('/serv/next-serv/' + serv_id).success(function(response){
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.serv_id = serv_id;//what's the point of this?
            , 5000);
        });
    };
}]);
```

I also modified the code to be more inline with the angular way.

Better Answer

your modified html code

```
<p>@{{serv_id}}</p>
<select class="form-control" id="serv" ng-model="service_id" ng-change="selectServ(service_id)">
        <option value="179">Serv 1</option>
        <option value="180">Serv 2</option>
        <option value="181">Ser 3</option>
</select>
 <a href="" class="btn-getnum" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remote-serv-modal">
     Get this serv <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
 </a>
```

your controller

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller("servController", ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', 'yourServletService', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, yourServletService) {
    $scope.selectServ = function(service_id){
        yourServletService.get(service_id, function(servlet){
            $scope.serv_id = service_id;//what's the point of this?
        });
    };
}]);
```

example service for your servlet

```
angular.module('yourApp').factory("yourServletService", [
    '$http', function($http) {
        return (function(ext) {
            return ({
                get: get
            });

            function get(service_id, success, error) {
                var request = $http('/serv/next-serv/' + service_id);
                return request.then(function(res){
                    if(success){
                        success(res.data);
                    }
                }, function(res){
                    if(error){
                        error(res.data);
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    }
]);
```

Also I don't know if it is on purpose or not but you have both "service_id" and "serv_id" which will be the same most of the time.

Comment: But OP is already calling $apply(). Neither OP's approach or this answer are correct angular approach since should be using `$timeout` service not `setTimeout`

Comment: @charlietfl I agree that $timeout should be used instead, but that was my quick answer to his question to fix as few of the pieces so that he understands what the intial issue was.  My following answer provides a better way for him to do things and not use the timeout altogether.

Comment: @BryanEuton - "a better way for him to do things" should not include code like serv_id = $('#serv').val()

Comment: @jbrown I agree.  That's why I didn't use that in my second answer. I'll update code to better segregate the two.

Comment: @BryanEuton - serv_id is undefined when you use it here:  $scope.serv_id = serv_id;  Also, $scope.selectServ is just floating out there ... its no longer part of the controller code.  This really isn't a very good answer and I'm not sure it even gets to the issue in the question.  Your not doing NewbieLearner any favors by offering a quick answer that doesn't answer the question and introduces new problems.  I'm resisting the urge to down vote in hopes that you fix your answer or remove it.

Comment: @jbrown he never gave us the controller code which is where the $scope.selectServ resides. I went ahead and updated the code.  I saw that I had a typo which causes an error. I raised the same question about the serv_id. NewbieLearner didn't explain it's purpose.

Comment: @BryanEuton - I see what you're saying about no controller code but putting all of you answer code all in one code block made it hard to recognize that.  You're correct that NewbieLearner never answered the question about serv_id (or any other) so I would exclude that code from your answer as it makes it look like you are recommending code that wont execute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114032/discussion-between-bryan-euton-and-jbrown).